# See if user is admin in Windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows-7, admin

I want to make a function to determine if a user, whose ID is passed with parameter, is an admin. I am able to do this for the currently logged in user with -

```
        public static bool IsAuthorizedUser()
    {

        WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(); 
        WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity); 
        return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator); 
    }
```

but I want to check any user passed in. So the signature would change to

```
public static bool IsAuthorizedUser(string username_to_check)
```

How can I do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You apparently need to know the password of the user in question, take a look at this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabhkv/archive/2008/05/29/windowsidentity-impersonation-using-c-code.aspx

Comment: and this one too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx

Comment: Is there any way to get around that? That is what I want. I just simply want to check if the user is an admin. I don't see why I would have to know their password for that..

Comment: if there was a way around that wouldn't that be a HUGH Security issue? Think about it.

Comment: do you want to check if the user is a domain admin or just local admin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Identifying if a user is in the local administrators group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064217/identifying-if-a-user-is-in-the-local-administrators-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working how I wanted with UserPrincipal. Thanks for the all of the feedback.

```
 public static bool IsAuthorizedUser(string userId) 
 {
     PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
     UserPrincipal usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userId);

     bool result = false;
     if(usr == null)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("usr is null");
     }
     else
     {
         foreach (Principal p in usr.GetAuthorizationGroups())
         {
             if (p.ToString() == "Administrators")
             {
                 result = true;
             }
         }
      }
      return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you need to look into the declaration of WindowsIdentity to see if there are methods to retrieve a user identity from it's string name.

Comment: There is a constructor for it. It'll return true for my username, but whenever I create a new user in administators and run the code, it always crashes with the message "The referenced account is currently locked out and may not be logged on to."

Comment: @Sterling I think you need to use the password of the user in question.

Comment: normaly, after that user is authenticated, we attribute the roles  to the identity, and we attach to CurrentThread of application

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this code

```
if(principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    //Passed
}
```

Comment: This would probably return `true` for every user that is logged on, right?

Comment: exactly in this case, with distinction between authentification and authorisation, i think that Sterling want verify the authentification in this services

Comment: I think the OP wanted to be able to tell if a particular user, not necessarily the logged in user was a member of the Administror's Group.