# Get local administrators users' names using C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm wondering if I can get witch users belongs to my local administrator group and list them. Is there any way to do that using C++? Any WinAPI way, maybe?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You've outlined two tasks: 1) Get a list of user accounts - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593333/how-to-get-all-windows-user-account-name?rq=1 and 2) See if a user is a local administrator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064217/identifying-if-a-user-is-in-the-local-administrators-group?rq=1.  At least do some basic research yourself to find an answer before posting here. Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Administrators group may contain other groups.  Depending on your needs, you might need to enumerate them iteratively.  (There may also be weird edge cases, e.g., if the sysadmin has foolishly added INTERACTIVE to the Administrators group, I'm not sure what will happen.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [NetUserGetLocalGroups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370655(VS.85).aspx) and [NetUserGetInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370654(VS.85).aspx) to retrive your information and check the value of `usri1_priv` in the [USER_INFO_1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371109(v=VS.85).aspx) structure.

I think something like this should get you started (taken from MSDN):

```
BOOL IsUserAdmin(VOID)
/*++ 
Routine Description: This routine returns TRUE if the caller's
process is a member of the Administrators local group. Caller is NOT
expected to be impersonating anyone and is expected to be able to
open its own process and process token. 
Arguments: None. 
Return Value: 
   TRUE - Caller has Administrators local group. 
   FALSE - Caller does not have Administrators local group. --
*/ 
{
BOOL b;
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY NtAuthority = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
PSID AdministratorsGroup; 
b = AllocateAndInitializeSid(
    &NtAuthority,
    2,
    SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID,
    DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    &AdministratorsGroup); 
if(b) 
{
    if (!CheckTokenMembership( NULL, AdministratorsGroup, &b)) 
    {
         b = FALSE;
    } 
    FreeSid(AdministratorsGroup); 
}

return(b);
}
```

You can also consult this [page](http://vcfaq.mvps.org/sdk/21.htm) (it's old, but it should work)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have/recommend any code example of that?

Comment: Thank you so much, George. I will give it a try.